# tcp timestamp, record time required to return a reply

Tags: c, linux, sockets, tcp, timestamp

I am trying to time ( seconds, ms, microseconds) a reply from a server , my client is sending a small packet to the server and the server is replying to the client.Now what I want is a way to insert a timestamp in the packet sent from the client to the server and the server appends its own timestamp to thet packet and returns it to the client. when the client receives that packet, it finds the difference between both times and returns this difference as the roundtrip time + server porocessing time.

My problem is that I know there is a timestamp option with tcp sockets but there are no examples on the net for it.If anyone can guide me in the right direction that would be great.

Thanks
OS : ubuntu 11.10
language : C
socket : BSD

Answer (score 1):

Is the client single threaded? If so and if you are only interested in measuring the time taken for the round trip + processing time all you have to do is measure the time taken on the client side to send a packet and receive the response corresponding to it. 
So just get the time in milliseconds before the client does a send, then get the time in milliseconds after the client receives the response. The diff in these two is the round trip time + processing time. Of course this only works when the client is single threaded (i.e. it does a send and then immediately calls recv and waits for the response from the server)

Answer (score 0):

If you're interested in performance measurement, you might be better installing wireshark http://www.wireshark.org/ and looking at the packet log. This will give you accurate timings without changing the code or stack you're measuring.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on how deep down the rabbit hole you want to go...

If you want to specifically use TCP packets (as in your tags) the most straightforward method would be to send a packet from client to server with the payload consisting of only a current timestamp. When the server receives the packet, append the server's timestamp to the payload and return it to the client.

Make sure both client/server are timesynced as well.